# Algorithm for smoothing the edges of a polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, computational-geometry

I use Node.js and Concave hull algorithm for isolating UK postcode sectors.
This is what I get for now:
[image]

So now, I need to smooth boundaries to look like this:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea which algorithm should I use?

Comment: [Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) variants come into mind

Comment: The problem is that you have multiple disjoint polygons, but want to draw a line *between* them. I could try to represent areas between those polygons, and then "squeeze* them to lines in some way. Or "grow" the polygons until they touch.

Comment: How would I grow them until they touch? What should I use?

Comment: @elektro_pionirka you could search for *polygon offsetting* for growing them and *polygon intersection detection* for detecting whether they touch

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lots of ways of doing this. I'm inclined to cite some kind of bezier interpolation (http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/).

@amit gave another great clue about how to solve the problem, splines are actually pretty useful for smoothing polygons. See the related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/how-to-smooth-the-polygons-in-a-contour-map

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are *at least* 2 approaches to this:

- **Curve fitting** algorithms(best for your use case)
- **Rammer-Douglas-Peucker** algorithm (simpler to implement)

The Rammer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm reduces the node count of a polygon - this  will not smooth it in the sense that it will make it curvy, it will simply reduce the nodes(roughness), whilst struggling to keep the polygon in it's original shape as much as possible

Although what you are, *most probably*, after is a Curve fitting algorithm through a series of points.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731213/algorithm-for-path-simplification-and-smoothing-of-2d-trajectories/27735435#27735435) I've made (*and the answer above, which is more descriptive*) for solutions to this.